# ajax POST respond

Tags: php, jquery

I use niceEdit as a html editor and a mysql for back end. The process I will send the data into a php using AJAX.

Heres my html code:

```
<div class='atabcontent'>
    <form id='apostform' method='POST'>
        <input name='request' type='hidden' value='atabaddnew' />
        <textarea id='aposttextarea' name='area1' style='width:780px; height: 400px; margin: 10px auto 0 auto;'cols='40'></textarea>
    <div style='height: 5px;'></div>
    <button id='apostsubmit'>Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and heres the ajax code.

```
$("#apostform").submit( function () { 
    //add a loading bar first
    $('div.atabcontent').append("<img class='loading' src='media/loading.gif' />");
    //send data to processor.php
    $.post(
        'processor.php',
        $(this).serialize(),
        //here, where we're going to manage the respond from the processor.php
        function(data){
            //remove the loading bar
            $('.atabcontent img.loading').remove();
            //output the respond
            $('div.atabcontent').html(data).show();
        });
    return false;   
});
```

and heres the php file (processor.php).

```
<? //this a processor e.g. post, delete, edit etc..
    //check if a post "request" is present..
    if (isset($_POST['request']))
    {
        //check if what type of request, if request type is equal to atabmenu then..
        if ($_POST['request'] === "atabmenu")
        {
            echo $_POST['data'];
        }
        elseif ($_POST['request'] === "atabaddnew")
        {
            echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['area1']);
        }
        //end
        //else if no request then go to fail.php along with the error code of "unable to     process the data"
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: fail.php?error=unable to process the data");
    }

?>
```

as you can see on the above code, it should work fine, but the respond from the php file that has been fetch by the ajax respond handler is empty and seems like there is no data that has been sent or neither has been received also i tried this

```
$("#apostform").submit( function () { 
    var data = $('#apostform textarea').val();

    alert (data);
    return false;   
});
```

but there the alertbox content is empty and as you can see in the code, it should alert a box with the value of the "#apostform". I tried a normal form, i mean no ajax and its work fine because i can see the data has been receive because it display the data receive from the form.

hope someone could help me on pointing out on what seems the problem on this. anyway i use niceEdit textbox http://nicedit.com/

PS: im open in any suggestion, recommendation and idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why did you used $_POST['request'] === "string"; == should be used instead

Comment: @MateiMihai: just to make sure that the comparison is absolute :D

Answer (score 1):

Your submit function seems to have a few syntax errors in it

```
$("#apostform").submit( function () { 
    var data = $('#apostform textarea').val(); // missing equals sign and closing apostrophe

    alert (data);
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: ah ok right, thanks. my bad it just a little mistake of typing the code when im posting my issue here, anyway it still doesnt work.

Comment: When asking questions make sure to copy your exact code as it would make it impossible to find the correct solution otherwise.

Comment: If you target the textarea directly instead of using apostform do you get a value back, e.g. `var data = $('#aposttextarea').val();`

Comment: no but if i use a normal form, i mean no ajax then it works fine.

Comment: but if i do this "echo "Asdasd";" instead of echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['area1']);, this "Asdasd" is sent back so, im sure now the data is sent successfully and receive successfully by the php file.